# Filter custom post type shortcode output by category WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I've created a custom post type for a "Clubs" section on a site, and I need to filter those clubs by their categories, using a shortcode.

Not entirely sure why the shortcode isn't working to filter the clubs by category (it does display all clubs).

For example, if one of the categories is AV Clubs, I've tried using both the title [club category="AV Clubs"] and the slug [club category="av-clubs"].

```
// Shortcode
function shortcode_club_viusu( $atts ) {
//default arguments
$args = shortcode_atts( array(
    'cat' => null,
    'category' => '',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'posts_per_page'=> -1,
    'post_type' => 'club'
), $atts );

$content = "";

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    //beginning of the FAQ element
    $content .= '<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">';

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $content .= '<li>';
        $content .= '<div class="collapsible-header">'.get_the_title().'</div>';
        $content .= '<div class="collapsible-body"><p>'.get_the_content().'</p></div>';
        $content .= '</li>';
    }

    //closing the FAQ element
    $content .= '</ul>';

} else {
    $content .= "No Clubs found";
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'club', 'shortcode_club_viusu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing one line from the list above:

```
'cat' => null,
'club_tax' => '',
'category' => '',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'date',
'posts_per_page'=> -1,
'post_type' => 'club'
```